# How to put attached properties to child item

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Let's assume I have a component like this

```
RowLayout {
    MyItem {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        ... // other properties
    }
    MyItem {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        ... // other properties
    }
}
```

in which `MyItem.qml` is defined like this

```
Rectangle {
    ... // other properties
    // Layout.fillWidth: true
    // Layout.fillHeight: true
}
```

Can I put `Layout.fillWidth` to `MyItem`, so that I don't need to repeat it in `RowLayout` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I put Layout.fillWidth to MyItem, so I don't need to repeat it in RowLayout ?

I think the question has the answer in it: if you don't want to repeat, just use the [`Repeater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) type. The documentation states that

> **Items instantiated by the Repeater are inserted, in order, as children of the Repeater's parent.** The insertion starts immediately after the repeater's position in its parent stacking list. This allows a Repeater to be **used inside a layout**.

The example which follows in the documentation uses `Row` but the very same approach can be applied to other layouts, e.g. `RowLayout`. Actually, it works for any type with attached properties as per the `Repeater` nature ("insert items inside parent").

Here is an example. Assume we have defined an `Example` type.

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Rectangle {
    property alias text: inner.text
    color: "steelblue"

    Text {
        id: inner
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pixelSize: 30
    }    
}
```

We can add the layout properties to our `Example` type inside the `Repeater`, for instance like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    RowLayout {
        id: row
        anchors.fill: parent

        Repeater {
            model: 6               

            delegate : Example {
                text: index
                Layout.fillWidth: true    // layout options added in the delegate
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                Layout.maximumWidth: parent.width / model.length
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [`model`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#model-prop) property of the `Repeater` can be either an array of strings or another model, as usual.

This approach is flexible enough to combine several `Repeater`s to create more complex structures. See for instance the following example in which `Text` is used to fill the screen inside a `GridLayout`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 2
        columns: 6

        Repeater {
            model: grid.columns
            Text {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.row: 0
                Layout.column: index
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                text: index + 1    // index of the repeater as text
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: grid.columns
            Text {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.row: 1
                Layout.column: index
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                text: index + 7
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, but it will end in an error whenever you decide to use that component in a context where it has no attached property named `Layout.fillWidth` or, more in general, whenever you decide not to use it as a top element within a layout.